# Инициализация неинициализированной памяти в аллокаторах

Tags: c++

При инициализации неинициализированной памяти в аллокаторах (например, в функции `uninitialized_fill`) используют `placement new` такого вида `::new (static_cast<void*>(&*buf))T(value)`, где `buf` - уже выделенный участок памяти, `T(value)` - вызов конструктора.

1. Для чего нужен `static_cast<void*>(...)`?
2. Для чего нужно `&*buf`?

Comment: Ну, поскольку размещающий `new` должен получать `void*` - соответственно, нужно приведение...

Comment: @Harry обязательно `void*`?

Comment: Мне казалось, что да, но тут пусть гуру скажут. Если и нет - то все равно корректнее приводить к `void*`, как я понимаю. Был бы я 100% уверен - я бы писал ответ, а так я пишу всего лишь комментарий :)

Comment: @Harry согласен, [вот](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) 9 и 10

Answer (score 6):

> Для чего нужен `static_cast<void*>(...)`?

Приведение к `void*` нужно, чтобы исключить возможность вызова пользовательского размещающего `new`. [Пример](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JdYX7uxaiujVO99L):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { };

void* operator new(std::size_t, A* a) {
    std::cout << "user new\n";
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A* p = static_cast<A*>( malloc(sizeof(A)) );

    new (static_cast<void*>(p)) A; // built-in
    new (p) A; // user-defined
}
```

> Для чего нужно `&*buf`?

Т.к. `buf` это в общем случае, не просто голый указатель, а итератор, то пара `&*` используется для получения адреса (голого указателя). В более правильном варианте эта конструкция будет выглядеть и вовсе как:

```
std::addressof(*buf))
```

Использование [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) необходимо по причине того, что `operator&` может быть перегружен для типа `*buf`.